# Jsoup: appending child <input> element to a <foorm> doesn't affect the form data

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing, html-parser

The following unit test fails:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    String html = "<html><form id=\"myform\"></form></html>";
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element inputElement = document.createElement("input");
    inputElement.attr("name", "any_name");
    inputElement.attr("value", "any_value");
    Element formElement = document.getElementById("myform");
    formElement = formElement.appendChild(inputElement);
    List<Connection.KeyVal> formData =  ((FormElement)formElement).formData();
    Assert.assrt(1 == formData.size());
}
```

Questions:

1. is it a bug or do I do something wrong?
2. is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `input` element to the form!

Look at the documentation of [`addElement​(Element element)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/FormElement.html#addElement(org.jsoup.nodes.Element)):

> *Add* a **form control** element to this form.

So, in your case, you have to add the following line to your code before the assertion:

```
((FormElement) formElement).addElement(inputElement);
```

Comment: In this case, the input element is not added to the HTML tree

Comment: @Vladimir You're correct! Fixed.

Comment: Just trying to understand what does the FormElement class need the elements property?  Why the formData() method cannot just iterate children()?

Comment: You're going to have to ask @JonathanHedley. ^^